# Issue with gdb on ubuntu with gcc 4.4.3

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

i am using gcc 4.4.3 on ubuntu 10.4 32bit machine.
i use 'gdb' to debug my code. Since few days i am seeing that whenever i debug code gdb steps into the c library functions used in the code also(like printf,fgets etc). This shows a long list of calls from one function to other.see the attached screen shot.
Previously gdb was working fine just stepping over my own code.
Maybe i am being novice !! But it is sometimes really irritating when gdb shows me numerous lines which i am not interested in the present context.

If someone can guide me as in how to turn off/on this feature and what can be cause of it being switched on on its own(i don't remember doing anything).
Many thanks.[image]

Comment: Did you use the `step` command, which steps into function calls, or the `next` command which skips over function calls? To step out of a function, you can use the `finish` command.

Comment: i used the 'step' command after reaching a breakpoint. i used to do that previously also but then it never went into any of the lib functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i used to do that previously also but then it never went into any of the lib functions

You (or someone) have installed `libc6-dbg` package. Before that, GDB couldn't step into `libc` functions, because they didn't have any debug info. Now they do, and it can.

Either get out of the habit of typing `step` when you want `next`, or un-install `libc6-dbg`.

Comment: @ Employed Russian.. thanks for the reason behind this. i had installed valgrind some days back maybe that installed the libc6.dbg with it...

Comment: Yes: `valgrind` indeed requires `libc6-dbg` on Ubuntu -- Valgrind needs to know about internals of `ld-linux.so.2`, and that info is *only* available from `libc6-dbg`.